# wordpress performance in huge load

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, innodb

I have a wordpress site that sometimes within 5 minutes has a huge load of users (2000 users in a shared host). I have a cache and other minor performance checks but still got a problem with the loading site. My main problem is database mysql. my server get 4 core and 8 gig of ram. Are there any advice for wordpress mysql sites or any config for better mysql performance?

I tried to change MyIsam to Innodb and have a redis object cache plugin but still doesn't change a lot.

Comment: Have you installed [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: no but i am gonna. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance improving suggestions.